# How would you approach this PSD to HTML?

Tags: html, css, psd

I have just started practicing converting PSD's to HTML/CSS. But sometimes you see PSD's and it just seems impossible to craft using html and css.

Like the one here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx0dl.jpg

Thanks alot

Comment: This question is off topic to a programming Q&A site. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

The way you should approach this is the same as you would approach any other PSD to HTML, divide it in blocks in your head and start from the top.

Here I made a very rough example of how you could divide this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2yp2.jpg

Comment: That's exactly how I was about to show to split that up. Good thing I clicked through to your link first.

Answer (score 0):

Use grid lines in photoshop to divide your image in different sections and create slices from there. You can even export to html once you've done that and it will create the css styles required too.

You can find a video explaining how to it here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVfxe4pqvo8

Answer (score 0):

Well, start with the basics:

- A central content container. Unfortunately, images only describe the layout with one particular screen resolution, but it looks like the designer wanted a centered element with fixed with, probably 960px.
- In that container, two headers. You can use the [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) CSS property to make borders round, but you'll probably need some `background` images for some icons.
- Add the example text, unstyled so far.
- Add the front image. You can probably crop it in Photoshop.